What Are the Minimum Required IAM Roles for App Engine and Compute Engine Default Service Accounts to Deploy with gcloud on a new Project?
In this document, it says:

Depending on your organization policy configuration, the default
service account might automatically be granted the Editor role on your
project. We strongly recommend that you disable the automatic role
grant by enforcing the iam.automaticIamGrantsForDefaultServiceAccounts
organization policy constraint. If you created your organization after
May 3, 2024, this constraint is enforced by default.
If you disable the automatic role grant, you must decide which roles
to grant to the default service accounts, and then grant these roles
yourself.
If the default service account already has the Editor role, we
recommend that you replace the Editor role with less permissive roles.
To safely modify the service account's roles, use Policy Simulator to
see the impact of the change, and then grant and revoke the
appropriate roles.

I also noticed that the Default compute service account seems to be also affected and has automatic role grant disabled by default.
What are the less permissive roles that need to be granted to the App Engine Default Service Account, and maybe also the Default compute service account, on a new project, that will allow you to successfully run gcloud app deploy?
I tried to deploy without any of the roles granted and, of course, I got a permission-related error; however, when I looked at an old project and manually granted the previously automatically granted roles, I was able to successfully deploy. I now want to follow the recommendation of Google to replace with less permissive roles, but I don't know what those roles would be, and if it has to be for both the Default compute service account and the App Engine Default Service Account.

I would say: app engine creator. Here the doc: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/roles

On a brand new project, I have tried giving the App Engine Default Service Account only the following Roles:
App Engine Creator, App Engine Deployer, Cloud Build Editor, Service Account User, and Storage Object Admin.
When I deploy, I still get the same error no matter what, abbreviated:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Failed to create cloud build: com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcClientException: <eye3 title='/ArgoAdminNoCloudAudit.CreateBuild, FAILED_PRECONDITION'/> APPLICATION_ERROR;google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1/ArgoAdminNoCloudAudit.CreateBuild;invalid bucket

I want to also show this bit of the error:
default Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account does not have access to the bucket
it could not fit in the comment above

@ Inn0v8_m8 As per this doc there is a change in the default service account of App Engine. The earlier service account used to be {projectNumber}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. As per doc current service account format is {projectName}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

@ Inn0v8_m8 see this stack case 1 and Stack case 2 helpful to resolve your issue.

I can think of two solutions to get the least required permissions:
First solution
Grant roles that work for you and then check the recommendations provided by Policy Intelligence. You should get a list of all used and unused permissions so you can create a custom role with the least required permissions.
Second solution
Remove all permissions from these Service Accounts, try to run the command of your choice, and then check Cloud Logging for logs of which permissions are missing to complete the command. Then create a custom role only with permissions that you get from logs. Probably you will need to iterate over this process a couple of times until the command will succeed. This approach of course shouldn't be used on Service Accounts that are being used by others.
